# expandable list view gives wrong group position, only works correctly without view holder

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I can't proceed without using the view holder pattern however because I am running countdowns in every list and Expandablelistview becomes choppy without it. Maybe its a simple fix. Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lobby, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();

        viewHolder.lobbyItemExpandIndicator = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lobbyItemExpandIndicator);
        viewHolder.draftEnding = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lobbyDraftEnding);
        viewHolder.gameType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lobbyGameType);
        viewHolder.accepting = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lobbyAccepting);
        viewHolder.gamesInDraft = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lobbyGamesInDraft);

        //viewHolder.draftEnding.setText(groupPosition + "");


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {


        viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final ContestItem contest =  mContests.get(groupPosition);

    //setCountdown(viewHolder, contest);


    viewHolder.gameType.setText(contest.getGameType());
    viewHolder.accepting.setText(contest.getAccepting());
    viewHolder.gamesInDraft.setText(contest.getNbaGamesAmnt());

    if (isExpanded) {
        viewHolder.lobbyItemExpandIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.w_dash);
    } else {
        viewHolder.lobbyItemExpandIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.w_down);
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolderItem {
    TextView draftEnding;
    TextView gameType;
    TextView accepting;
    TextView gamesInDraft;
    ImageView lobbyItemExpandIndicator;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep your countdowns in group model object instead of keep in views, views are reused each time. so you must keep countdown in your group model and then on get view restore countdown each time.

for example if your displaying data is:

```
private HashMap<MenuCategoryModel, List<ChildCategoryModel>> mMainMenuExpandableList;
```

then you must keep your countdowns in `MenuCategoryModel` or if for each subitem then in `ChildCategoryModel` and on get views group or child (whatever needed) - restore countdowns.

Comment: awesome tip, I will make sure to do it that way. Not sure it is my only problem though. In the above code I have my countdowns commented, but still when I set one of the views to groupPosition and then expand list view I notice that the group positions become out of order.

Comment: I do not understand how to set it up the way you suggested. If I have the countdown timer in my model, then I do not know how to restore it and set my textview in getView.

Comment: in view you display only visual part, you can with countdown place current time value in the same model and when you get view display this value, view is used only to display right?, and you can get countdown by reference )

Comment: thanks, this answer helped me figure out a big part of my problem. I will post another questions more specific to the viewGroup position problem I am having.

Comment: Stepan, I have tried to set up my Countdown timers the way you suggested, but I am still having a problem. If you would like to take a look, I have asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646632/setting-countdown-timer-in-expandablelistview-recycling-issue