# Setting Countdown Timer in ExpandableListView - Recycling Issue

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Okay, I previously wrote this question, but have narrowed the problem down since then so decided to rewrite it. What I am trying to do is set a Countdown Timer in each group in ExpandableListView. Right now I do this by starting each countdown in my model object, then when I inflate each group I get the remaining time for that item and pass it to a new instance of countdown timer in the adapter. This all works perfectly except when I expand a child list and scroll some of the parent groups far off the screen to where they are recycled. When they are recreated, all of the views are set correctly except for the textview containing the countdown, this one switches. So what I see are two or more groups with the wrong countdown. The groups are still in order and the model object is still the correct one. So my specific questions are two: 1. Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to accomplish? 2. Could this be happening because I am accessing the textview that sets the countdown from an inner class? I originally thought this problem had something to do with expandable list returning the wrong viewGroup, now I am not so sure.

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    final GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;



    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lobby, null);
        groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(groupViewHolder);


    }else{

        groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    groupViewHolder.lobbyItemExpandIndicator = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lobbyItemExpandIndicator);
    groupViewHolder.gameType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lobbyGameType);
    groupViewHolder.accepting = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lobbyAccepting);
    groupViewHolder.gamesInDraft = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lobbyGamesInDraft);
    groupViewHolder.mContestItem = (ContestItem) getGroup(groupPosition);
    groupViewHolder.draftCloses = groupViewHolder.mContestItem.getDraftCloses();


        if (groupViewHolder.draftCountdownTimer == null) {
            groupViewHolder.draftEnding = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lobbyDraftEnding);

            groupViewHolder.draftCountdownTimer = new CountDownTimer(groupViewHolder.draftCloses, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    long durationSeconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;

                    groupViewHolder.draftEnding.setText((String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d:%02d:%02d", durationSeconds / 3600,
                            (durationSeconds % 3600) / 60, (durationSeconds % 60))));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    groupViewHolder.draftEnding.setText("Draft Finished");
                }
            }.start();
        }


    groupViewHolder.gameType.setText(groupViewHolder.mContestItem.getGameType());
    groupViewHolder.accepting.setText(groupViewHolder.mContestItem.getAccepting());
    groupViewHolder.gamesInDraft.setText(groupViewHolder.mContestItem.getNbaGamesAmnt());

    if (isExpanded) {
        groupViewHolder.lobbyItemExpandIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.w_dash);
    } else {
        groupViewHolder.lobbyItemExpandIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.w_down);
    }

    return convertView;
}

public class GroupViewHolder {

    TextView draftEnding;
    TextView gameType;
    TextView accepting;
    TextView gamesInDraft;
    ImageView lobbyItemExpandIndicator;
    CountDownTimer draftCountdownTimer;
    ContestItem mContestItem;
    long draftCloses;

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on *groupPosition returns the wrong value in getGroupView after I scroll the list*? It's a unclear on what seems to be the concern. Are you getting an error? Incorrect group item? Something like that?

Comment: after trying to figure this out for a full day I think I narrowed it down and rewrote the problem. Have another look if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

I repeat one more time, you again get item from viewholder, view holder - read this two words and try to understand them:

1) viewholder is for hold views, this mean it's for to hold results for such operations as findViewById (this is heavy operation for app).

2) viewholder reuses views, DON'T keep information that is related to item in list, it's only for views! Coz if you store info in next your scroll it viewholder can contain information from another item.

3) all data information, including countdowns must be hold in item model, right in your hashmap and must be restored from it in `onBindViewholder` only in this way is the right way.

here is sample how to do it from my code:

in adapter you define:

```
private HashMap<CategoryModel, List<CategoryModel>> mMainMenuExpandableList; // This is your categories;
private List<CategoryModel> mMainMenuKeysList; // This is your keys to be easier already in separated list;
```

in constructor you set this values:

```
public CategoriesExpandableListAdapter(HashMap<CategoryModel, List<CategoryModel>> hashMap, List<CategoryModel> keyList){
    mMainMenuExpandableList = hashMap;
    mMainMenuKeysList = keyList;
}
```

then you  override `getGroup` and `getChild`:

```
@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return mMainMenuKeysList.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return mMainMenuExpandableList.get(mMainMenuKeysList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}
```

then in `getGroupView`:

```
final CategoryModel groupObject = (CategoryModel) getGroup(groupPosition);
```

in `getChildView` you can get both objects to act:

```
CategoryModel groupObject = (CategoryModel) getGroup(groupPosition);
CategoryModel childObject = (CategoryModel) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
```

and now when you got proper object from hash for category you can get from that object your countdowns and display them.

Hope this will help, 
Have a nice day :)

Comment: thats fine, I guess I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! I will try to implement this and let you know if I have success!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am still having the same problem. I appreciate your time trying to help, but I have decided to hire a freelancer. Again, I appreciate your time. Have a good one!

Comment: Probably you are doing something wrong ) in anyway finally you will survive :)